# Vue editing object in array changes other objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am having problem with editing array inside of object inside of array.
When new option in checkboxes-options (in checkboxe-smodal) is added or deleted or edited it affects all other "checkboxes" elements in array. What am I doing wrong or is there better way to do it.

this is questdata.js

```js
const quests = [

{
    idno: 1,
    icon: "fas fa-file-word",
    type: "textbox",
    name:"Textboks",
    label:"Things is just a title for text box",
    placeholder: "Tell the story",
    helptext:"Make sure that both clients and employees know wat you want them to do ",
    columnwidth:"col-12",
    value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet, dolor eget tempor interdum, nisi tortor pellentesque ex, eget porta purus ante suscipit magna. Etiam ac scelerisque tellus, sit amet tincidunt sem. Nam non sem vel lectus imperdiet mattis. Cras scelerisque ac neque ut lacinia.",
    required: false,
    tabindex: null,
},
{
    idno: 2,
    icon: "fab fa-500px",
    type: "freeresponse",
    name:"Free Response",
    label: "Are you truly happy",
    placeholder: "Enter what you want",
    helptext:"I will tell you what to do",
    columnwidth:"col-12",
    value: null,
    required: false,
    tabindex: null,
},
{
    idno: 3,
    icon: "ti-check-box",
    type: "radiobuttons",
    name:"RadioButtons",
    label: "Yes or no is the question",
    placeholder: "",
    helptext:"You got to decide right now",
    columnwidth:"col-12",
    value: null,
    required: false,
    tabindex: null,
    options: [ 'YES', 'NO' ],
    selected: []
},

{
    idno: 4,
    icon: "far fa-calendar-check",
    type: "checkboxes",
    name:"Check Boxes",
    label: "You got something to check",
    placeholder: "",
    helptext:"I will check when you do",
    columnwidth:"col-12",
    value: null,
    required: false,
    tabindex: null,
    options: [ 'Check me once', 'Check me twice', "Check one more time" ],
    selected: []
},
```

this is vue file

```html
<template>

  <div>
    <b-modal v-model="newquestmodal" title="Create brand new questionnaire template" size="xl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          Insert Element
          <b-card>
            <b-list-group v-for="element in elementlist" :key="element.idno">
              <b-list-group-item class="mt-2" href="#" @click="newquestion(element)"><i :class="element.icon"></i>
                {{ element.name }}</b-list-group-item>
            </b-list-group>
          </b-card>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <p>New questionaire</p>

          <b-form-input v-model="quests.name" placeholder="Enter the name of the questionaire"></b-form-input>
          <b-card class="h-100 row">
            <div v-for="quest in quests" :key="quest.tabindex">
              <b-card v-if="quest.type === 'freeresponse'" :class="quest.columnwidth">
                <b-card-text>
                  <div style="float: right">
                    <i @click="freeresponsemodal = !freeresponsemodal" class="far fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt ml-2"></i>
                  </div>
                  <p>{{ quest.label }}</p>
                  <b-form-input v-model="quest.value" :placeholder="quest.placeholder"></b-form-input>
                </b-card-text>
                <!-- =============================================================================================                 -->
                <b-modal v-model="freeresponsemodal" ok-only title="Edit this element">
                  <b-card>
                    <b-card-text>
                      <span>Edit question</span>
                      <b-form-input v-model="quest.label"></b-form-input>
                      <span>Edit placeholder</span>
                      <b-form-input v-model="quest.placeholder"></b-form-input>
                      <span>Edit helptext</span>
                      <b-form-input v-model="quest.helptext"></b-form-input>
                      <span>Edit default value</span>
                      <b-form-input v-model="quest.value"></b-form-input>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <span>Required?</span>
                          <b-form-checkbox v-model="quest.required" value="'required" unchecked-value="unrequired">
                          </b-form-checkbox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <span>Edit columnwidth</span>
                          <multiselect v-model="quest.columnwidth" :options="['col-3', 'col-6', 'col-9', 'col12']"></multiselect>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card>
                </b-modal>
                <!-- ==============================================================================================                -->
              </b-card>
              <b-card v-else-if="quest.type === 'checkboxes'" :class="quest.columnwidth">
                <b-card-text>
                  <div style="float: right">
                    <i @click="checkboxesmodal = !checkboxesmodal" class="far fa-edit"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt ml-2"></i>
                  </div>
                  <p>{{ quest.label }}</p>
                  <b-form-checkbox-group id="checkbox-group-1" v-model="quest.selected" :options="quest.options" name="flavour-1"></b-form-checkbox-group>
                </b-card-text>
                <!-- =============================================================================================                 -->
                <b-modal v-model="checkboxesmodal" ok-only title="Edit this element">
                  <b-card>
                    <b-card-text>
                      <span>Edit question</span>
                      <b-form-input v-model="quest.label"></b-form-input>
                      <span>Edit helptext</span>
                      <b-form-input v-model="quest.helptext"></b-form-input>
                      <span>Edit available options.</span>
                      <span>Add, remove or edit options</span>

                      <div v-for="(option, index) in quest.options" :key="index">
                        <b-input-group class="mb-1">
                          <b-form-input v-model="quest.options[index]">
                          </b-form-input>
                          <b-input-group-append>
                            <b-button @click="$delete(quest.options, index)" size="sm">
                              <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></b-button>
                          </b-input-group-append>
                        </b-input-group>
                      </div>

                      <b-button @click="adoption(quest)">Ad Another option</b-button>

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <span>Required?</span>
                          <b-form-checkbox v-model="quest.required" value="'required" unchecked-value="unrequired">
                          </b-form-checkbox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <span>Edit columnwidth</span>
                          <multiselect v-model="quest.columnwidth" :options="['col-3', 'col-6', 'col-9', 'col12']"></multiselect>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card>
                </b-modal>
                <!-- ==============================================================================================                -->
              </b-card>
            </div>
          </b-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {
    quests
  } from "@/questdata";
  import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
  import DatePicker from "vue2-datepicker";
  import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";
  import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
  export default {
    components: {
      DatePicker,
      Multiselect,
      ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    data() {
      return {
        newquestmodal: false,
        elementlist: quests,
        quests: [],
        qindex: 1,
        test: null,
        freeresponsemodal: false,
        checkboxesmodal: false,
        textboxmodal: false,
        dropdownmodal: false,
        radiobuttonsmodal: false,
        editor: ClassicEditor,
      };
    },
    mounted() {},
    methods: {
      show() {
        this.newquestmodal = true;
      },
      newquestion(element) {
        this.qindex++;
        const newElement = element;
        newElement.tabindex = this.qindex;
        this.quests.push(Object.assign({}, newElement));
      },
      editme(quest) {
        console.log(quest);
        this.freeresponsemodal = true;
        this.test = quest;
      },
      adoption(quest) {
        console.log(quest.tabindex);
        let arr = quest.options.slice();
        arr.push("");
        quest.options = arr;
      },

    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, what do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: No problems other then quests objects are changing as if the have same index